# Hibernating a machine from within

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a script running on an EC2 instance that may choose to hibernate.

If I was going for `stop`, I could just `sudo poweroff`. But I'm not sure how hibernation is done internally.

I'm considering the following approach

1. set up aws on the instance following https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-metadata.html
2. get instance id from metadata
3. `aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids $OWN_INSTANCE_ID --hibernate`

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really get hibernation to work, but some steps in that direction:

```sh
sudo systemctl start hibagent
sudo systemctl hibernate
```

Comment: It seems that `hibagent` has been replaced with `hibinit-agent`. For me, `systemctl hibernate` fails with `Failed to hibernate system via logind: Not enough swap space for hibernation`. I'm still looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

At least for the Ubuntu 20.04 AMI, hibernation is triggered by the `acpid` service, which effectively runs the following command:

```sh
sudo /etc/acpi/actions/sleep.sh button/sleep SBTN 00000080 00000000
```

If you examine the script, all that really matters is that the second argument is `SBTN`. (Thus you can substitute the command with `sleep.sh x SBTN`.) The script first enables the extra swap created by the `hibinit-agent` service in the file `/swap-hibinit` and then runs `systemctl hibernate`.

Note: for reference, I also see the following ACPI event (viewable with `acpi_listen`):

```
button/sleep LNXSLPBN:00 00000080 00000003
```